# How to add item to list

Tags: javascript, reactjs, list, react-native, variables

MainPage

```
    export class Diet extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          list: [],
        };
      }
    
      addToList(item) {
        const list = [...this.state.list, item];
        this.setState({ list });
      }
    
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            <Text style={styles.txtYourMeals}>Your Meals</Text>
                     <FoodList items={this.state.list} />  <--------
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
    
 export default Diet;
```

FoodList

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export class FoodList extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Content>
          <List>
            <ListItem>
              <Text>FoodCreated</Text>
            </ListItem>
          </List>
        </Content>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default FoodList;
```

FoodCreate

```
export default function FoodCreate({ navigation: { goBack } }) {
  const [FoodName, setFoodName] = useState("");

  return (
    <Container>
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              name="arrow-back"
              onPress={() => goBack()}
              style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}
            />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>Add Food</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon  <-----------
              name="checkmark"
              style={{ fontSize: 25, color: "red" }}/>
          </Button>
        </Right>
      </Header>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Food Name"
          placeholderTextColor="white"
          style={styles.inptFood}
          value={FoodName}
          onChangeText={(FoodName) => setFoodName(FoodName)}
        />
    </Container>
  );
}
```

So I'm trying to let the user type a `Food Name` in a TextInput in the `FoodCreate` page and pressing the button `checkmark` to add that food name in the `FoodList` which is displayed in the `MainPage`. I started but I have no idea on how to proceed. It's a basic grocery shopping list in which you type a food name and add it to your list and every time you do that you insert a new item.

Comment: Instead of ```(FoodName) => setFoodName(FoodName)``` try ```(e) => setFoodName(e.target.value)```

Comment: Yes, but as of now the app doesn't do I want, I'm trying to understand how to make it work

Comment: You are trying to add the Food Names in an array, to display it in another component right? You need to pass down the array wich you want to manipulate, down to the children components in orders for them to modify and display the data. So in your case, you want to ```.push()``` your food name in your list array.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to tell the parent component i.e. `MainPage` that a new food item has been created.

This should look something like this in your `MainPage`

```
render() {
        return (
          <>
            <FoodCreate addToList={addToList}/>
            <View>
              <Text style={styles.txtYourMeals}>Your Meals</Text>
                     <FoodList items={this.state.list} />  <--------
            </View>
        );
      }
```

Now, this `addToList` would be available to your `FoodCreate` component which you can call whenever you create the food item. Also, I don't see any `Save` button in your `FoodCreate`. I think that's where you might want to add a click listener so that whenever user clicks on that button, you call the `addToList` method